Blowup of a simplicial affine toric variety at the fixed point of the torus action
In this question, all cones are strongly convex, rational, polyhedral cones. We shall adopt the convention that, if a lowercase Greek letter $\sigma$ denotes a simplicial cone, then the uppercase letter $\Sigma$  denotes the barycentric subdivision of $\sigma$, which is constructed as follows:

Let $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be $\sigma$'s ray generators, and let $u_0 = u_1 + \dots + u_n$.
Let $\Sigma$ be the fan whose cones are generated by the subsets of $\{ u_0, \dots, u_n \}$ that do not contain $\{ u_1, \dots, u_n \}$.

My goal is to show that, if $\sigma \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a simplicial cone of dimension $n$, then the toric variety $X_\Sigma$ is the blowup of $X_\sigma$ at the unique fixed point of the torus action, henceforth “the origin”. I already know that the result holds when $\sigma$ is a smooth cone, i.e., when $u_1, \dots, u_n$ form a basis of $\mathbb Z^n$. Now I want to reduce the general case to this known case.
My attempted solution begins as follows:

Let $\gamma \subset \mathbb R^n$ be the first orthant, i.e., the cone whose ray generators are the standard basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$. Define $f : \mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z^n$ by $f(e_i) = u_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$. Notice that $G = \mathrm{coker}(f)$ is finite, because $f$'s image has rank $n$. Then,

$f$ sends $\gamma$'s faces to $\sigma$'s faces, so $f$ induces a finite toric morphism $\varphi : X_\gamma \to X_\sigma = X_\gamma / G$.
$f$ sends $\Gamma$'s cones to $\Sigma$'s cones, so $f$ induces a finite toric morphism $\Phi : X_\Gamma \to  X_\Sigma = X_\Gamma / G$.

The identity map $\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z^n$ also induces proper birational toric morphisms $X_\Gamma \to X_\gamma$ and $X_\Sigma \to X_\sigma$, which, together with $\varphi$ and $\Phi$, form a nice little commuting square.
Since $\gamma$ is a smooth cone, $X_\Gamma$ is the blowup of $X_\gamma$ at the origin. So my goal is to show the operations “blowing up at the origin” and “quotienting by the action of $G$” commute.

So far so good. Both “blowing up at the origin” and “quotienting by the action of $G$” are well understood operations on the commutative algebra side:

Blowing up at the origin: Let $A$ be the coordinate ring of an affine algebraic variety $V$ and $\mathfrak m$ the maximal ideal of a point $p \in V$. Then the graded ring $B(A) = A \oplus \mathfrak m \oplus \mathfrak m^2 \oplus \mathfrak m^3 \oplus \dots$ is the coordinate ring of the cone over $\mathrm{Bl}_p(V)$.

Quotienting by the action of $G$: Let $A$ be the coordinate ring of an affine algebraic variety $V$ and let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $V$. Then the ring of $G$-invariants $A^G \subset A$ is the coordinate ring of $V/G$.


So it stands to reason that I should take $A$ to be the coordinate ring of $X_\gamma \cong \mathbb A^n$ and $\mathfrak m$ the maximal ideal of the origin. Then my goal is to relate the following graded rings:

The blowup algebra of $A^G$, which describes the blowup of $X_\sigma$ at the origin:
$$
B(A^G)
    = A^G \oplus \mathfrak m^G \oplus (\mathfrak m^G)^2 \oplus (\mathfrak m^G)^3 \oplus \dots
$$

The ring of $G$-invariants in $B(A)$, which describes the quotient $X_\Sigma = X_\Gamma / G$:
$$
B(A)^G
  = (A \oplus \mathfrak m \oplus \mathfrak m^2 \oplus \mathfrak m^3 \oplus \dots)^G
  = A^G \oplus \mathfrak m^G \oplus (\mathfrak m^2)^G \oplus (\mathfrak m^3)^G \oplus \dots
$$


It is clear that $(\mathfrak m^G)^k \subset (\mathfrak m^k)^G$, hence $B(A^G) \subset B(A)^G$. However, I do not think the reverse inclusion is true in general. For example, if we take $A = k[x,y]$ and $G$ the cyclic group of order $2$ acting by reflections, then $xy \in (\mathfrak m^2)^G$, but $xy \notin (\mathfrak m^G)^2$.
Now, this much is fine. I am aware that the homogeneous coordinate ring of a projective variety $X$ encodes information not only about the abstract variety $X$, but also about a specially designated tautological line bundle over $X$. So it is perfectly possible that $B(A^G)$ and $B(A)^G$ describe the same abstract variety with two different tautological line bundles.
From previous experiments, I know that $u_0$ is not always a ray generator. In particular, when $G$ is a cyclic group, $u_0$ is $|G|$ times the generator of the ray that contains $u_0$. (And I suspect that this is true whether $G$ is cyclic or not.) Could this be somehow related to the difference between the homogeneous coordinate rings $B(A^G)$ and $B(A)^G$?
At this point, I should probably take a step back and ask - how far am I from solving this problem?

The statement I wanted to prove is false. Consider, for example, $\sigma \subset \mathbb R^2$ generated by $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (-2,3)$. The toric variety $X_\sigma$ is isomorphic to the surface $V(z^3 - xy) \subset \mathbb A^3$, whose tangent cone at the origin is the union of the planes $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Therefore, the exceptional divisor of the blowup of $X_\sigma$ at the origin is the union of two $\mathbb P^1$'s. However, in $X_\Sigma$, the preimage of the origin is an irreducible curve.
